# Where to find cross section data for $e^{-}$ + $p$ $\longrightarrow$ $p$ + $e^{-}$?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, scattering-cross-section, data

Where to find cross section data for $e^{-}$ + $p$ $\longrightarrow$  $p$ + $e^{-}$ ?

[PDG's cross-section data listing](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/hadronic-xsections/hadron.html) does not include it.

Comment: At what energies and momentum transfers? Also do you have a polarized beam or target?

Comment: Any energy/momentum transfer for which data is available.

Comment: The point is that data are available over very wide ranges in energy. SLAC ran at up to $50\text{ GeV}$ electron beams. My dissertation project to $\mathrm{H}(e,e'p)$ at $5.0$ and $5.5\text{ GeV}$ beams and $Q^2$s between $3.3$ and $8.1\text{ GeV}^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can search the HEPDATA database at http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/hepdata/ with the query string

```
[reac = e- p --> e- p]
```

and the first result will be:

"Jefferson Lab. Measurement of the elastic electron-proton cross section in the Q**2 range from 0.4 to 5.5 GeV**2"

Answer (score 6):

The answer is highly dependent on the scale of the momentum transfer.

The figure of merit is $Q^2$ is the squared momentum transfer, and in some regimes the missing energy $\omega = \epsilon' - \epsilon$. The formalism is usually developed in the lab frame with a stationary proton target and a energetic electron beam. We write $Q = \mathbf{k}' - \mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{k} = (\epsilon,\vec{k})$ and $\mathbf{k}' = (\epsilon',\vec{k}')$ are the four momentum of the incident and scattered electron respectively.

- If $Q^2 \ll m_p^2$ then you can treat the proton as a point particle to first order and you can simple look this up. In the upolarized case you use the [Mott cross-section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_scattering).
- For Q^2 on the same order of magnitude at the proton mass squared the problem is complicated enough that one typically uses a parameterized experiment results in the shape of a set of ["form factors"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_form_factor) (note that the formalism typically used at medium energies is different from but equivalent to that used at high energies). The [JLAB results that luksen links to](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19887/520) are among the highest precision available at this time.

  In nuclear physics parlance you get
  $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma}{\mathrm{d}\Omega} = \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma}{\mathrm{d}\Omega} \right)_{\text{Mott}} \frac{Q^2}{\left|\vec{q}\right|^2} \left[ G^2_\mathrm{E}(Q^2) + \tau \epsilon^{-1}G^2_\mathrm{M}(Q^2)\right] .$$

  To a first approximation you can use the dipole form for the form factors $$G_\mathrm{M} \approx \mu G_\mathrm{E} \approx \mu \left( 1 + \frac{Q^2}{0.71\text{ GeV}^2}\right)^{-2} ,$$
  where $\mu$ is the magnetic moment of the proton.
- For $Q^2 \gg m_p^2$ you are in the deep inelastic scattering regime and can treat the proton at a collection of bound partons. The phrase you're looking for is ["structure functions" (PDF link)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/rpp2011-rev-structure-functions.pdf).