# Angle of deflection of an atomic nucleus

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, scattering

when firing a proton (for example) to an atomic nucleus, from a distance $D$, the deflection angle of the proton $\alpha $ to the type of changes atomic nuclei? or always constant?

Answer (score 1):

As with any other scattering reaction, it depends.

It should be obvious that heavier nuclei have a higher charge and thus a stronger repulsive effect. Likewise lower energy projectiles will be deflected through larger angles, but heavier mass projectiles will be less affected.

Assume a elastic interaction and $Q^2$ not more than, say, $0.1\text{ GeV}^2$, you can deduce it from the energy and impact parameter simply by integrating the electric force.

For stronger elastic interactions you'll need to use a more complete treatment including the form factors of the proton and the nucleus. Inelastic interaction are more complicated still.

---

You can find the first layer of math in [an older answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19889/520), which still applies to first order despite the differences in the reactions.

Most college quantum mechanics books do a treatment of a simple case. You're looking for the chapter or section in which "scattering" first appears.

Answer (score 0):

Not an up-to-date formula, but there is Rutherford's impact parameter formula (IIRC experimentally verified). It may be a useful approximation for you.

$$D=\frac{Z_1 Z_2 e^2}{4\pi \epsilon _o mv_0^2} \cot\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Or,

$$\alpha =2\cot^{-1}\frac{4\pi D\epsilon _0 m v_0^2}{Z_1 Z_2 e^2}$$

where $Z_1,Z_2$ are the atomic numbers of nucleus and projectile, and $m_0$ is the mass of the projectile.