# List of cross sections?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, scattering-cross-section

Sometimes I need to look up a certain cross section, say the inclusive Z production cross section at $\sqrt{s}$ = 7 TeV. Is there a place where 'all the' cross sections are tabulated (experimental and theoretical), like the branching ratios are in the [PDG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_Data_Group)? I know it might be hard, because there is often not 'the' cross section and you have to take into account generator cuts and the likes, but still there should certainly be a review somewhere?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19886/2451

Comment: PDG has more than branching ratios. It has crossection plots http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2012-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf from experimental measurements. I do not think it reasonable that there exists a compilation of theoretical values. You would have to search the literature for the specific reaction's theoretical models available.