# Cross-Section Compendium?

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, scattering-cross-section

Are there any books or references that exhaustively list cross-sections for various processes in QED or particle physics? I think such a book would make for a very useful reference, and in particular I would like to practice deriving cross-sections.

Comment: This is very close to being a duplicate of [List of cross sections?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64311/).

Comment: Also related: [Where to find cross section data for e- + p -> p + e-?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19886/).